# Can I use pyspark rdd map with the result of functools.partial applied to a global scope function?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to use python functools partial to create a function to use with the spark rdd map function. The problem is that the closure includes the files that are not on the cluster task nodes. What is the best way to work around this? What I'd like to do is:

```
def f(row, p1, p2):
   ...

def transform(rdd, p1, p2):
   mapF = functools.partial(f, p1=p1, p2=p2)
   return rdd.map(mapF)
```

but the error I get is that the module where this code is written doesn't exist. I know I could ship the code to the other nodes with spark options - but I'm in development mode in a jupyter notebook at this point - the spark app was started once with fixed parameters, I'd have to find a hacky way (I think) to manually get the updated files to the task nodes.

The other thing is to give up on my nice function in global scope, if I put it inside my transform function, then I can use partial, that is this works:

```
def transform(rdd, p1, p2):
   def f(row, p1, p2):
       ...    
   mapF = functools.partial(f, p1=p1, p2=p2)
   return rdd.map(mapF)
```